# Apache setup 000-default.conf file

Tags: apache

I am sure this is a simple one:

I have vagranted up a machine and setup the LAMP, and the IP is configured to 10.0.0.10.

In my Windows machine, I have modified the hosts file and added one entry named as "rsywx_remote". The ping from my Windows machine to my vagrant machine is OK. Load the "rsywx_remote" in browser from my Windows machine is also fine. The connectivity is of no problem.

I then SSH to my vagrant machine and modified the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` like this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
        DocumentRoot "/www/rsywx/web"
        ServerName rsywx_remote
        ServerAlias rsywx_remote

        <Directory "/www/rsywx/web">
                Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
                AllowOverride All
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from 127.0.0.1
                Deny from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Restarted my vagrant Apache service, and it still points to the default page, not the one I expected.

Any hints?

Comment: Did you enable NameVirtualHosts in your apache config? `NameVirtualHost 10.0.0.10` And why is your VHost listening to 127.0.0.1 when your apache listens to 10.0.0.10 ?

Comment: Added NameVirtualHost in 000-default.conf, no use and prompts "NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release". 

Changed "Allow from 127.0.0.1" to "Allow from all". 

Restarted Apache, no effects.

Comment: Did you check your apache error logs while starting up? You did restart it?

Comment: No useful output in /var/log/apache2 log files. I am pretty sure the Apache is restarted. I even halt the vagrant machine and up it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

That will listen on all addresses