# Apache2: How to Host an website in a remote VM?

Tags: php, apache2, hosting, virtualhost

I installed apache2 server on a cloud VM (Remote accessing with SSH to Ubuntu 18.04 Server) and i want to open a test web page when typing the VM IP address on my browser. Which configuration should i do ?

Also when typing the VM IP address i do not get the Default Ubutu Apache web page even if 000-default.conf is enabled ?

is there a specific configuration to put apache2 online ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to open the required ports for the Apache Web Server: verify that ports 80 (http) and 443 (https) are open on the cloud VM.

For https, you have to supply self-signed or valid TLS certificates (in PEM format).

For reference, check [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433955/apache-setup-000-default-conf-file) StackOverflow questions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually when typing the server IP on my browser, i get the PLESK Web Page, but i expect to get Apache default web page. Can you help me on that ?